# How To Remove Unwanted space in Navigation Bar When Using min-width:400px In The Body?

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I'm trying to make navigation bar with a fix `min-width:400px` in the body so that when using a smartphone the design will not displace. When I tried to minimize it less than `400px` the navigation list in the phone has space. Please teach me how to make it disappear. Thank you.

**CODE**

https://codepen.io/venJ7/pen/LYPBgEE

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Comment: try to give .Nav-sm { left:0; position:fixed; top: 75px; width: 100%; height: calc(100vh - 75px) }

Comment: @JustCode It's working but I don't want to used `position:fixed`

Comment: Have you checked with the parent container's width of the classes ".head" & ".sm". And we could not find css pertaining to ".sm" class here. try avoid using pixels. Always check the code in Browser inspector as most of the problems get resolved there.

Comment: @vssadineni `head`'s parent is `<header>` tag and for the `class="sm"` is `display="none"` ..I always use browser inspector and tried everything I can think of but it's no use.

Comment: I was trying to replicate the same but unfortunately the above code is not full, so would you please create a codepen example to help you out?

Comment: @vssadineni I edited the post. The link for codepen is there.

Comment: I understood the problem, please remember to add width, padding, margin all with-in 100%; and your calculation will not go wrong.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rakeshnayak/t9dugspy/3/ try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[look at the below image how the width and padding is adding up to the total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao4aI.png)

[image]

Comment: #header .head {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0 15px 20px;
} is going out as 100% + 20px width.

Comment: .Nav-sm {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    background: #4FC696;
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    z-index: 99999;} is absolutely positioned but the parent is not set to relative, so how it will take the 100% width of the parent?

Answer (score 1):

You write CSS code for body tag is body {min-width: 400px; font-size: 100%;}, I think the problem is there, replace your CSS code for body tag with following code that will help you,

```
body { 
  min-width:100%; font-size:100%;
}
```

Comment: I used that before but my content will be displaced whenever the width getting smaller.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, you set with 100% with the margin, so please exclude it by `box-sizing`

```
 #header .head {
     margin: 0;
     width: 100%;
     padding: 20px 0 15px 20px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```